# ubuntu 12.04 server and tftp access violation issue on put command

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I installed tftp as per this document:
http://icesquare.com/wordpress/solvedtftp-error-code-2-access-violation/

I followed this to the letter 3 times and every time I put a file I get:

root@CiscoCFG:~# tftp localhost
tftp> put test
Error code 2: Access violation
tftp> root@CiscoCFG:~# tftp localhost
tftp> put test
Error code 2: Access violation

If I touch the file name chmod 777 the file then do a put it works perfectly fine.

My config is as follows:

service tftp
{
protocol = udp
port = 69
socket_type = dgram
wait = yes
user = nobody
server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args = -s /svr/tftp
disable = no
}

the directory /svr/tftp permissions are 777:
drwxrwxrwx  3 nobody nobody  4096 Nov 14 10:32 svr

This thing should have full permissions as would anyone who wanted to write or read from that directory. I see nothing in the logs im really stumped on this.  If the file is already in the directory I can read it all day long, I just cant make NEW files, can not put them, but I can do get's, I can only put to an existing file with permissions @777.

Thanks

Comment: you didn't follow the instructions to the letter;
"server_args = -s /svr/tftp"  should be "server_args = svr/tftp -s"